# How to add postgresql jar in GGST

Tags: postgresql, grails, jdbc

I have the db and current jar postgresql-9.4.1207.jre7.j to conect.
Now, from GGST im unable to find the option to add my jar.it seems to be similar to maven but still cant find the option

[image]

Finally i wonder if the driverClassName should be org.postgresql.Driver

```
dataSource {
pooled = true
driverClassName = "org.postgresql.Driver" 
username = "root"
password = "root"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

With Grails you don't actually add the jar. Instead, you declare the dependency in **build.gradle** (for Grails 3). For example, in the `dependencies` closure add the Maven artefact for postgresql like this:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile 'org.postgresql:postgresql:9.4.1207.jre7'
}
```

For Grails 2 the concept is the same except the file is **grails-app/conf/BuildConfig.groovy**.

Comment: it seems to be the way , for that reason i update my question

Comment: Interesting. I know the Maven artifact 'org.postgresql:postgresql:9.4.1207.jre7' resolves because I just tested it in plain Groovy with the `@Grab` annotation. The line *grails-postgresql-9.4.1207.jre7.zip.sha1* seems odd though; I don't see why *grails* is in the name. For what it's worth, try running `grails refresh-dependencies` and give it another go.

Comment: Oh, and your `driverClassName` is correct. So that's not the problem.

Comment: i added some parte of the view from my project explorer